# Fortran program errors

Tags: fortran90

I wanted your help in writing a program to convert fortran array (n, m) in a table (p, 3).

I tried with this program:

```
program Temp
implicit none
real,dimension (23250,27)::table
real::time
integer::i
integer::j
integer::wl
integer::al
  i=1,23250  
read(*,*) time(i),wl(i),(table(i,j),j=1,27)
 j=1,27 
alt(j)=j
write(*,*) time(i),alt(j),table(i,j)
continue
continue 

endprogram Temp
```

but error messages are displayed as:

```
 D:\Travaux de thèse\modeling\essay\essay.f90(9) : Error: Syntax error, found ',' when expecting one of: <END-OF-STATEMENT> ;
  i=1,23250  
-----^
D:\Travaux de thèse\modeling\essay\essay.f90(11) : Error: Syntax error, found ',' when expecting one of: <END-OF-STATEMENT> ;
 j=1,27 
----^
D:\Travaux de thèse\modeling\essay\essay.f90(10) : Error: Constants and expressions are invalid in read-only I/O lists.   [TIME]
read(*,*) time(i),wl(i),(table(i,j),j=1,27)
----------^
D:\Travaux de thèse\modeling\essay\essay.f90(10) : Error: Constants and expressions are invalid in read-only I/O lists.   [WL]
read(*,*) time(i),wl(i),(table(i,j),j=1,27)
------------------^
D:\Travaux de thèse\modeling\essay\essay.f90(12) : Error: This name has not been declared as an array.   [ALT]
alt(j)=j
^
Error executing df.exe.

essay.exe - 5 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Can anyone can help me?
T
hanks you in advance.

Comment: S'il vous plaît, voyez: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: Je voudrais une kilo de pomme de terre, s'il vous plais. Sorry, that's all I remember :-)

Answer (score 0):

from your example code alone it is a bit difficult to figure out where this code is going. Where is your array 'array' you mention in the question defined? If you want to loop over something, you need to use the 'do' statement[1]. Furthermore I would try to access the dimension of that array programmatically, so you don't have to hard code it. The following code snippet is not complete, but maybe it gets you going.

```
program Temp
implicit none
real,dimension (23250,27)::table
integer, dimension(2) :: table_shape
real::time
integer::i
integer::j
integer::wl
integer::al

table_shape = shape(table)
do i=1, table_shape(1)
    read(*,*) time(i),wl(i),(table(i,j),j=1,27)
    do j=1, table_shape(2)
        alt(j)=j
        write(*,*) time(i),al(j),table(i,j)
        !continue
        !continue 
    enddo
enddo

endprogram Temp
```

Best,
Max

[1] http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Fortran_control